# How to collect queries sent to mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to collect for an 1 hours all the queries reaching my mysql instance (Amazon RDS). How to do it? Is there any special command, I could use.

Comment: The first idea that would come to my mind is Googling `mysql log queries`?

Comment: Or `mysql log queries rds instance`

Comment: If using Amazon RDS (AWS), try [their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Monitoring.CloudTrail.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read something about General Query Log. In [THIS LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)

Must remember to switch general_log in global settings to ON

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```